# Why does RSA produce different results with same key and message?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, character-encoding, rsa

I will post my code. Sorry for the confusion.

```
StringBuilder texto1 = new StringBuilder("LALALLA");
byte[] x = texto1.toString().getBytes();
try {
  Cipher cifrado = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
  cifrado.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key1.getPublic());
  x = cifrado.doFinal(x);
  String texto;
  texto = new String(x, "UTF-8");
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(publicKey.toString());
  String teste = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    teste += x[i];
  }
  jTextPane1.setText(teste);
  //cifrado.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);
  byte[] y;
  // x= texto.getBytes();
  //y = cifrado.doFinal(texto.getBytes());
  //texto = new String(y,"UTF-8");
  jTextPane2.setText(x.toString());
} ...
```

That's the code in an action on a button. Everytime that I run this code, with the same keys, texto1 on encryption returns a different result like `[B@52a0b1e1` or `[B@3e55abb3`

Comment: First of all: **yes**, encryption is **supposed** to do that. And second: The string you're printing is the `toString()` of the `byte[]`, that's *entirely unrelated* to its content.

Comment: PKCS#1v1.5 padding is dangerous; consider using OAEP if possible.

Answer (score 6):

The `toString()` method of arrays in Java doesn't display the content of the array. Instead, it shows the component type and an identifier based on the location of the array in memory.

If you want to see the content of the array, you have to iterate over its elements. And, in this case, you'll have to decide how you want to encode the byte elements to text. It looks like you are trying to do this with your variable `teste`, but I'd recommend something like this:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : x) 
  buf.append(String.format("%02X", b));
String teste = buf.toString();
```

This will generate a hexadecimal representation of your ciphertext. You can't create a `String` from random 8-bit values as you attempt with the variable `texto`, because the bytes will generally not form valid UTF-8 encoding sequences. You'll end up with a lot of replacement characters in the text (�).

With a hex (or base-64) encoding, you will see that the cipher text still varies randomly. That's because RSA's PKCS #1 padding schemes uses random data to pad the message before encryption. This deliberate feature of RSA prevents an attacker from recognizing when the same message is being sent.